# html dom and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the elements from textboxes `nameBox` and `foodBox` to be displayed in the paragraph id=message after the submit button is clicked, with the message:

```
“Hello <name in namebox>! We want to let you know that <food in foodbox> has 50% discount in our restaurant!”
```

But i can't figure out how to do that. I'm pretty sure i'm doing something (if not all) wrong but since i'm new at this i can't figure it out what.

```
<body>

    <br>
    <br>

 <div> 
 <p id="message"></p>  
 </div>   

    Enter your name: 
    <input type="text" id="nameBox" value=""><br>

    Enter your favorite food 
    <input type="text" id='foodBox' value=""><br>


<button id="submitButton">Submit</button>

<script>
   var parent=document.getElementById("message");
    var child=document.getElementById("nameBox");
parent.removeChild(child);
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go :

```
<html>
<head>

<script>


function showText(){

    var name=document.getElementById("nameBox").value;
    var food=document.getElementById("foodBox").value;

    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML="Hello " + name + " ! We want to let you know that has 50% discount in our restaurant! for " + food;

}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<br>
<br>
<div id="msg"> 
</div>   

Enter your name: 
<input type="text" id="nameBox" value=""/><br>

Enter your favorite food 
<input type="text" id="foodBox" value=""/><br>


<input type="button" id="submitButton"  onclick="showText()" value="Submit" />

</body>
</html>
```

You can make your alignments as you wish, try to use firebug (https://getfirebug.com/) in case of finding UI related issues. It is pretty easy to figure out what is wrong in the UI

Answer (score 1):

That's because parent is not the parent of child. To make it so, edit your code to put the two input elements inside the `<p>` tag:

```
<p id="message">
    Enter your name: 
    <input type="text" id="nameBox" value=""><br>

    Enter your favorite food 
    <input type="text" id='foodBox' value=""><br>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call function on clicking submit button and then change the message.

```
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="somefunction()"/>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
function somefunction() {
  var fieldNameElement = document.getElementById('message');
  fieldNameElement.innerHTML = “Hello ! We want to let you know that has 50% discount in our restaurant!” ;
}
```

While changing the `innerHTML` you can add appropriate formatting tags as well.

Also you should add inputs in a table, and add border's and required formatting if required:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
   Enter your name: 
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" id="nameBox" value=""><br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    Enter your favorite food 
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" id='foodBox' value=""><br>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

You can also think about using a Javascript library which provides lot of methods to make your life easy, would suggest [JQUERY](http://jquery.com/)

Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

Check your HTML. Maybe it should look like this?

```
<div id="message"> 
    Enter your name: 
    <input type="text" id="nameBox" value=""><br>

    Enter your favorite food 
    <input type="text" id='foodBox' value=""><br>

    <button id="submitButton">Submit</button>
</div>
```